# Finding angle of triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

In a triangle ABC, M is the midpoint of BC, P is any point on AM and PE, PF are perpendiculars to AB, AC respectively. If EF is parallel to BC, then find value of angle A

I tried extending BA to Point D such that DC becomes parallel to AM but I couldn't figure it out......Plz help
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Gun What you have stated above holds only for isosceles or equilateral triangles. quasi has in his answer correctly pointed out that it is not possible to determine the value of  $\measuredangle A$ for isosceles triangles. However, since your statement is also true for all equilateral triangles, you may write  $\measuredangle A= 60^o$.

Comment: Thanks @YNK .....

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to find angle $A$.

Let $\Delta ABC$ be an arbitrary isosceles triangle with base angles at $B$ and $C$.

Then the hypothesis is satisfied but angle $A$ can take any value strictly between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks for answering .... Really appreciate that